# How can I restore the interface size back to the default?

Tags: interface

I have inadvertently reduced all the menus on 2.82 to 2mm! I cannot see to change back. Despite having uninstalled/deleted all known traces of 2.82 residual memory seems to exist as all downloads and loadings of 2.83 are just the same. 2.80 loads fine.

Comment: FIXED!  Using the Preferences menu of 2.80 as a guide worked through Preferences/interface and slide sliders to increase size until I could see what I was doing, Cheers.

Comment: In the future look in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\ on Windows or $HOME/.config/blender/  on linux for your config files

Comment: If you have an answer, please add it in the answer box below instead of as a comment. Thanks.